# Pointer to function for unmanaged code in C#

Tags: c#, callback, pinvoke, intptr

I have a dll which accepts a struct that contains a pointer to a function to do a callback.

How can I get an IntPtr to a function of my application to build the struct?

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class OPERATION {
        public uint OperationID;
        public IntPtr Context;  
        public IntPtr Callback; -> How to pass this?
    }
```

Here is the delegate accepting the OPERATION struct

```
public delegate void MY_CALLBACK([In] OPERATION operation, [In] uint msgId, [In] IntPtr msgDataPtr);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [`Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getfunctionpointerfordelegate.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the [Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getfunctionpointerfordelegate.aspx) method may help you.